# "A hundred percent" vs. "hundred percent"

Tags: grammaticality, british-english, numbers, indefinite-articles

Which sentence is grammatically correct:

> - I'm a hundred percent sure
> - I'm hundred percent sure

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Hundred* by itself does not constitute a quantity.  You must have a number in some form:

> I'm **one** hundred percent sure.

or something else to provide a number — like "a" which denotes a singular quantity.

> I'm **a** hundred percent sure.

Without a number it is similar to saying

> I have milliliters of water. [How many milliliters?]

Answer (score 3):

One hundred is usually not said in English unless wishing to distinguish it with TWO, for example; in this case, A hundred is the idiomatic way of referring to ONE hundred. And, in agreement with a previously posted answer, without saying A (=ONE), no quantity would be indicated.